# How to detect the used columns from input dataframes in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I have a Spark application with many input dataframes with many input columns each.
My need in to detect which columns are really read and used by my transformations.
The only way I have found to do it is to dump the physical plan before each action with method `output_df.explain(true)` and then parse it to search which columns are part of it.
But I am wondering if there is a better way to do that ?

Comment: In my opinion, you got the good method to do that.
You can also check the spark UI and see the logs.